# Google Calendar API: how to access X-APPLE-TRAVEL-DURATION

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api, icalendar, google-api-php-client

When accessing as .ics my (Google) calendar contains Apple Calendar travel information:

`X-APPLE-TRAVEL-DURATION;VALUE=DURATION:PT45M`

(full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921899/how-do-the-x-apple-extensions-work-in-icalendars))

How do I retrieve this information using the Google Calendar API?
When listing the events this information is not included.
E.g.

```
  {

   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"...\"",
   "id": "...",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=...",
   "created": "2016-05-29T11:45:53.000Z",
   "updated": "2016-05-29T11:45:53.530Z",
   "summary": "test apple travel",
   "creator": {
    "email": "john@doe.com",
    "displayName": "John Doe",
    "self": true
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "john@doe.com",
    "displayName": "John Doe",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2016-05-30T13:00:00+02:00"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2016-05-30T13:30:00+02:00"
   },
   "iCalUID": "...",
   "sequence": 0,
   "hangoutLink": "...",
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  }
```

Comment: That property is not available in the APIv3 as far as I know.

Comment: Is that in general? Are [private vCalendar / iCalendar software extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Calendar_extensions) not available in the API? - I assumed these would show up under privateExtendedProperty / sharedExtendedProperty.

Comment: Yes, those are not available.